# Displaying theRatingBar in the list view

Tags: android, android-widget

After the completion of the Notepad tutorials I've managed to add a rating bar in the edit note section, allowing the user to interact with it and rate the note,this being saved in the SQL database. Now I'm trying to add the rating bar in the `fillData()` method which defines the row elements of the list allowing to easily populate the list with entries from the database. But the problem is that the program crahses because of the `R.id.rating` and I don't know how to fix it. Is there a way to display the rating along with the notes in the primary list view? Thank You

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list 
    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_RATING};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to 
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2,R.id.rating};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Comment: I don't have a stack trace but if R.id.rating is removed then it works...but it won't display the rating bar on the list view...which I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists/RateList) complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` only supports `TextViews` and `ImageViews` and does not support `RatingBar`

Refer for details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Now to display `RatingBar` in `ListView`, you have to use `CursorAdapter` and use its `newView` to create and `bindView` to set the rating value. You can also use `ListAdapter` which is more verbose to use.

Refer to:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

Comment: so how should I proceed in this case?is there something else I can use?

Comment: thanks but....I've tried that and I'm getting the error:"Cannot instantiate the type CursorAdapter"....and I get the same thing for the ListAdapter also

Comment: You cannot create their instances. `CursorAdapter` is `abstract` classes, so you have extend it and create your class. Implement the `newView` and `bindView` methods. `ListAdapter` is an interface and you have to implement it.

Comment: my class already extends ListActivity and the two methods netview andbindView take only 3 arguments,what should I do?